# How can I space this element in GitHub special readme file?

Tags: html, css, github

I am working on a GitHub 'readme' page for my GitHub profile I have this gif that I want to be off to the right but not too far over that it is excluded. GitHub seems to not let me use the `padding` style so I don't know how to do this. Note I am not very experienced in HTML/CSS so I'm trying my best. The line in question is the `<img/>` tag line.

code currently;

```
# Hi there i'm Hudson or ZombieKicker7! 

<img align="right" alt="GIF" src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1292677/screenshots/6139167/media/5387dc7e035b3efe9d94516044de66a4.gif" width="400" height="300" />

#### I'm currently:
```

results;
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0p4Y.png)

However, if I remove the `align="right"` style it will just go to its normal place in the code like so;
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYknH.png)

I hope this is enough information to explain the problem if not please ask and I would try to provide a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub does not let you use CSS or JavaScript in README files or other documents that it renders.  That's because allowing arbitrary styling or scripting poses a bunch of different problems and READMEs are designed to be simple.

First, scripting and styling can modify other page elements and spoof parts of the page, in addition to other security problems, so GitHub doesn't allow this for security reasons.  GitHub automatically sanitizes anything that's rendered using this type of HTML pipeline for this reason.

Second, allowing users to customize the appearance of items on the site with CSS can make the site hard to use or hard to read.  For example, people could make text too small or with too low of a contrast for most people to read, which poses accessibility problems.  GitHub wants people to have a good user experience and is required by law to be accessible.

So you may be able to use the `align` attribute here, but if it requires any sort of CSS, it won't be possible.  You'll need to either stick with mostly plain Markdown or AsciiDoc or similar, or put the content you want somewhere else where CSS is allowed.